# More fields than expected in UserCreationForm

Tags: django

I ve just create a project and setting authentification.
But for registeration, I m using UserCreateform expected to have username and password fields only. Instead I have many fields like last login, superuser_status, groups, etc... Where is my error ?

Forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class SignUpform(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2',)
```

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm
from .forms import SignUpform

def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, 'You are registered')
            # redirect to a succes page
            return redirect('home')

    else:
        form = UserChangeForm()

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'register.html', context)
```

My goal:

having only fields defined in signupform. thanks for helping

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: When the request method is GET you are using a UserChangeForm. This should be your SignUpForm

Answer (score 0):

Change you `views.py` to :

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, 'You are registered')
            # redirect to a succes page
            return redirect('home')

    else:
        form = SignUpform()

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'register.html', context)
```